# How to get array data to output only intger PHP

Tags: php, arrays, int

Currently on my dev site I'm using an array to output the number of players and total players on a server.

via the line `$info['Players']    = $server_cache_data[1];`

It shows this like

> 1601.5.1/5EmpireCraft - Factions - PvP!0250

as you can see on my website [here](http://dev.xitude.co.uk/minecraft-tracker/index.php)

How would i get this to only output it in intger (numbers)?

I have tried `string_resize($server_cache_data[1], 4)` to get it down to 4 hoping it will stop this but no luck.

Thank you for your time in advanced.

Note also the output you can see is being feed by two arrays the players and the total players controlled by `$info['MaxPlayers'] = $server_cache_data[2];`

Comment: Which integer out of this `1601.5.1/5EmpireCraft - Factions - PvP!0250` do you need to fetch?

Comment: As you can see here : http://www.minetrack.net/server/214 not my site the server as players and max players, that should output the same on to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's type juggling functionality:

```
echo intval("1601.5.1/5EmpireCraft - Factions - PvP!0250" + 0);
```

This returns the first integer number regardless of how many digits the number has.

Note: This works only if the number is the first part in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to get the `INT` value of out the last 4 characters,  you could use

```
$info['Players'] = intval(substr($server_cache_data[1],-4));
```

And if you want those last 4 digits even if they start with 0, you can remove the `intval()` call

```
$info['Players'] = substr($server_cache_data[1],-4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$str = server_cache_data[1];
$start = 0;
$length = 4;

$num = intval(substr($str, $start, $length)); // 1601
```